# Upload image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I try these code in controller:

```
public function uploadimage(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $destinationPath = 'uploads';
            $files = $request->image;
            $file_name = $files->getClientOriginalName();
            $files->move($destinationPath, $file_name);
            echo "Complete";
        } else {
            echo "No File";
        }
    }
```

My Html input file:

```
 <input name="image" type="file" id="image"/>
```

but i can't upload. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag? Like this `<form action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Oops thank you very much it's work when i put these

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider accepting answer below, as it has the same information plus the additional way to store the file

Comment: @ljubadr yes thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `storage::putFile('folder_name', $request->image)` this will return automatic generated filename and you can store that in your database.

And make sure your have your default file system set to public and your form has this `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: I'm late. I was researching for it.

Comment: If you are the first to answer, you are now late, by the way solution is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` he forget to add in form get

Comment: You are right, I'm contributing for the first time So i just wanted to post it away. This was the only question I could answer in my feed.

Comment: I wanted to say `you are not late`, instead `you are now late` my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile this works differently:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserAvatarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the avatar for the user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
        return $path;
    }
}
```

Source: [Laravel 8 - Filesystem > File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads)